# Upload video files to amazon s3 bucket from iOS

Tags: php, ios, video, file-upload, amazon-s3

I need to upload a video file to amazon s3 bucket from iPhone.Due to my requirement i have stored some informations regarding video file in server.

So my process is upload a video file to server and then upload the file from server to s3 bucket.It works properly for minimum duration videos(Less than 30MB).If i upload HD videos or large size videos(100MB) got error from s3 bucket.How can i get success for larger videos.